# How to display multiple images next to each other in one figure?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I'm using Julia, PyPlot and Images to handle some pictures. Because showing dozens of plots is out of the question I want to stack images like you can see below.

I have the image-data in an `Array{Array{Float64, 2}, 1}` already normalized.

---

The following code shows only the last, smallest image. The array is sorted from the largest to the smallest picture.

```
for i = 1:size(P, 1)
  imshow(P[i], "gray", interpolation = "none")
end
```

---

I want to achieve the following effect:

[image: Stacked images]

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution with Plots:

```
using Plots, TestImages
img = testimage("cameraman")
p = plot(
    axis = nothing,
    layout = @layout([a [b [c [d;_]; _]; _]]),
    size = (800,400)
)

for i=1:4
    plot!(p[i], img, ratio=1)
end
p
```

[image]

Comment: It's incredible how easy Plots makes everything. Thanks for the superb work, Tom!

Answer (score 2):

Here's two methods.

*1.* The quick but inflexible `subplot` one:

```
# create test image
using PyPlot, TestImages
img = testimage("cameraman");
img = [convert(Float64, i.val) for i in img[:,:]]';
```

```
# plot in desired positions
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(img); axis("off");
subplot(2,4,3); imshow(img); axis("off");
subplot(4,8,7); imshow(img); axis("off");
subplot(8,16,15); imshow(img); axis("off");
subplot(16,32,31); imshow(img); axis("off"); # ... etc
```

[image]

*2.* Manually specifying axes positioning:

```
# using same image as above
figure();
axes(position=[0,0,0.5,1]); imshow(img); axis("off");
axes(position=[0.5,0.5,0.25,0.5]); imshow(img); axis("off");
axes(position=[0.75,0.75,0.125,0.25]); imshow(img); axis("off");
axes(position=[0.875,0.875,0.0625,0.125]); imshow(img); axis("off"); # ... etc
```

[image]

Comment: PS: Figure saved using `savefig(filename, facecolor="black")` , to get figure background to be black as in your example

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a single array by concatenating the arrays for all the other images and filling in where you would like the empty space to be with zeros (or any other number)?

1. Make a new array of arrays where all inner arrays have the same height by padding bottom with zeros
2. `fullimage = cat(1, arrayofarrays...)`
3. `imshow(fullimage)`

(Sorry I'm on my phone so can't provide a working example for you!)